# Need advice on combining ORM and SQL with legacy system

Tags: c#, sql, orm, interface, business-objects

We are in the process of porting a legacy system to .NET, both to clean up architecture but also to take advantage of lots of new possibilities that just aren't easily done in the legacy system.

**Note: When reading my post before submitting it I notice that I may have described things a bit too fast in places, ie. glossed over details. If there is anything that is unclear, leave a comment (not an answer) and I'll augment as much as possible**

The legacy system uses a database, and 100% custom written SQL all over the place. This has lead to wide tables (ie. many columns), since code that needs data only retrieves what is necessary for the job.

As part of the port, we introduced an ORM layer which we can use, in addition to custom SQL. The ORM we chose is DevExpress XPO, and one of the *features* of this has also lead to some problems for us, namely that when we define a ORM class for, say, the Employee table, we have to add properties for all the columns, otherwise it won't retrieve them for us.

This also means that when we retrieve an Employee, we get all the columns, even if we only need a few.

One nice thing about having the ORM is that we can put some property-related logic into the same classes, without having to duplicate it all over the place. For instance, the simple expression to combine first, middle and last name into a "display name" can be put down there, as an example.

However, if we write SQL code somewhere, either in a DAL-like construct or, well, wherever, we need to duplicate this expression. This feels wrong and looks like a recipe for bugs and maintenance nightmare.

However, since we have two choices:

- ORM, fetches everything, can have logic written once
- SQL, fetches what we need, need to duplicate logic

Then we came up with an alternative. Since the ORM objects are code-generated from a dictionary, we decided to generate a set of dumb classes as well. These will have the same number of properties, but won't be tied to the ORM in the same manner. Additionally we added interfaces for all of the objects, also generated, and made both the ORM and the dum objects implement this interface.

This allowed us to move some of this logic out into extension methods tied to the interface. Since the dumb objects carry enough information for us to plug them into our SQL-classes and instead of getting a DataTable back, we can get a List back, with logic available, this looks to be working.

However, this has lead to another issue. If I want to write a piece of code that only displays or processes employees in the context that I need to know who they are (ie. their identifier in the system), as well as their name (first, middle and last), if I use this dumb object, I have no guarantee by the compiler that the code that calls me is really providing all this stuff.

One *solution* is for us to make the object know which properties have been assigned values, and an attempt to read an unassigned property crashes with an exception. This gives us an opportunity at runtime to catch contract breaches where code is not passing along enough information.

This also looks clunky to us.

So basically what I want advice on is if anyone else has been in, or are in, this situation and any tips or advice you can give.

We can not, at the present time, break up the tables. The legacy application will still have to exist for a number of years due to the size of the port, and the .NET code is not a in-3-years-release type of project but will be phased in in releases along the way. As such, both the legacy system and the .NET code need to work with the same tables.

We are also aware that this is not an ideal solution so please refrain from advice like "you shouldn't have done it like this". We are well aware of this :)

---

One thing we've looked into is to create an XML file, or similar, with "contracts". So we could put into this XML file something like this:

- There is an Employee class with these 50 properties
- Additionally, we have these 7 variations, for various parts of the program
- Additionally, we have these 10 pieces of logic, that each require property X, Y and Z (X, Y and Z varies between those 10)

This could allow us to code-generate those 8 classes (full class + 7 smaller variations), and have the generator detect that for variation #3, property X, Y and K is present, and I can then tie in either the code for the logic or the interfaces the logic needs into this class automagically. This would allow us to have a number of different types of employee classes, with varying degrees of property coverage, and have the generator automatically add all logic that would be supported by this class to it.

My code could then say that I need an employee of type IEmployeeWithAddressAndPhoneNumbers.

This too looks clunky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest that eventually a database refactoring (normalization) is probably in order.  You could work on the refactoring and use views to provide the legacy application with an interface to the database consistent with what it expects.  That is, for example, break the employe table down in to employee_info, employee_contact_info, employee_assignments, and then provide the legacy application with a view named employee that does a join across these three tables (or maybe a table-based function if the logic is more complex).  This would potentially allow you to move ahead with a fully ORM-based solution which is what I would prefer and keep your legacy application happy.  I would not proceed with a mixed solution of ORM/direct SQL, although you might be able to augment your ORM by having some entity classes which provide different views of the same data (say a join across a couple of tables for read-only display).

Answer (score 2):

"We can not, at the present time, break up the tables. The legacy application will still have to exist for a number of years due to the size of the port, and the .NET code is not a in-3-years-release type of project but will be phased in in releases along the way. As such, both the legacy system and the .NET code need to work with the same tables."

Two words: materialized views.

You have several ways of "normalizing in place".

1. Materialized Views, a/k/a indexed views.  This is a normalized clone of your source tables.
2. Explicit copying from old tables to new tables.  "Ick" you say.  However, consider that you'll be incrementally removing functionality from the old app.  That means that you'll have some functionality in new, normalized tables, and the old tables can be gracefully ignored.
3. Explicit 2-way synch.  This is hard, not not impossible.  You normalize via copy from your legacy tables to correctly designed tables. You can -- as a temporary solution -- use Stored Procedures and Triggers to clone transactions into the legacy tables.  You can then retire these kludges as your conversion proceeds.

You'll be happiest to do this in two absolutely distinct schemas.  Since the old database probably doesn't have a well-designed schema, your new database will have one or more named schema so that you can maintain some version control over the definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Although I haven't used this particular ORM, views can be useful in some cases in providing lighter-weight objects for display and reporting in these types of databases. According to their documentation they do support such a concept: [XPView Concepts](http://www.devexpress.com/Help/?document=XPO/CustomDocument2068.htm&levelup=true)